# how to think of $\sqrt{z} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ . Let $z = x + iy $. How can you write $f$ as u + iv  where $u,v$ are in terms of $x,y$ ? I tried to write $\sqrt{z} = e^{ \frac{ \log z }{2} } $. but this does not seem to help.

Comment: So, if you want to write it as $r = e^{i\theta}$, then the square root is easy to write. Here $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Comment: Can you write down the real and imaginary parts of $\log z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\theta=\text{Arg }z$, $r=\log|z|$,

$$e^{(\text{Log }z)/2}=e^{r/2}\big(\cos (\theta/2)+i\sin (\theta/2)\big)$$

You can also apply the formulae for $\cos (\theta/2)$ and $\sin(\theta/2)$ to express then in terms of $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$. Note also that $e^{r/2}=\sqrt{|z|}$.

You can also take a purely algebraic approach. Write
$$(u+iv)^2=x+iy$$
You get the system
$$\begin{cases}x=u^2-v^2\\y=2uv\end{cases}$$
which you should solve for $u$ and $v$. This will lead to a equation of the form $u^4+au^2+b=0$, and the expression for the solutions will have nested radicals.

Comment: Well constructed, especially giving the user both polar and Cartesian ways forward!  +1

Answer (score 1):

Write $x=re^{i\theta}$, then $\sqrt x=x^{\frac12}=\sqrt r e^{i\frac{\theta}2}$.

Comment: Haven't you essentially written what I wrote in the comment ?

Comment: @Shailesh It takes time for someone to write a solution and post it.  And during that period, others might have posted a comment or an answer. So, why are you concerned here?

Comment: @Dr.MV  You are right. I take back my comment. My apologies.

Comment: @Shailesh No worry.  Your comment here was actually just a question.  ;-))  I encourage you to post your useful thoughts as answers as others seem to see these more easily than they do comments.  And we are here as a community to help one another.  Best wishes.

Comment: @Dr.MV   Thanks. Since I do not usually like to post complete answers, I post them in comments. I have learnt a lot from the community in the last 4 months.

Comment: @Shailesh You're welcome.  And pleased to hear!!